# Would it be a good idea not to reload the tags tooltips on Stackoverflow?

Tags: discussion, tags, tooltips, optimization

Let's say I look at a tooltip:

[image]

If I look at it again, it will load again, even if I'm looking at the same one:

[image]

Wouldn't it be better for the user and the server to keep this loaded div somewhere and then simply show it it every time someone over the same tag on the page instead of reloading it ?

I know it's very minor, but I thought I'd bring it up anyways.

Comment: Or maybe just not load in the first place. (I must be to slow at moving my mouse because I keep having the popup appear when I don't want it to and it covers up what I was moving to click onto.)  ;-)

Comment: @jzd I don't know... I kind of like this feature even if I don't use it ^^

Comment: the feature is nice, but I don't really use it and find it gets in my way, but that is another conversation.